# Java Application with plug and play db

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, hibernate

My company has a product that we sell as a solution to mediocre firms, they are ok with using java but they have different opinions on db due to licensing and other technical/resource issues. 

 I was wondering if there is a way i can create the app in such a way that during installation we configure the database (select weather mysql/oracle and input/generate connection strings, allocate driver, e.t.c.) and it works similarly as the other db. I have heard about hibernate being able to generate table but havent ever worked on it before.
I need an opinion and if possible reference to a guide. thank you in advanced. sorry for a stupid question, i only know basics of java, haven't yet worked on ORM or any other framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

The JPA (java persistance API) allows you to do what you're looking for. You will be needing a JPA provider (such as [hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), [Apache OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/) or [eclipse link](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) among others).

You will be able to automatically create the schema of your database according to the objects you need to map into it.

Here are few links to get started:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/
- http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SettingUpJPA/SettingUpJPA.htm

Many JPA ressources will point to java ee ressources and tutorials, since it is heavily used with java entreprise edition, but the API itself can be used with the standard java platform.